Need to auto-disable a ticket buy option at midnight (any defined time) in React | Node
Below are my ideas (broken rather):

relying on setTimeout, but my users are in different time zone so assuming this won't be the best way of doing it.
setTimeout(() => { /*disable ticket*/ }, timeToDisable);


using node-schedule : With this approach the scheduler will be running on the node server so should I make a network call to request time every second? That sure doesn't sound right to me as well.
schedule.scheduleJob('00 15 * * *', () => {
    disableTickets(ticketsToDisable);
    console.log(`Tickets disabled ${ticketsToDisable}`);
});



What's a good way of doing this?

If the time (in UTC ideally) at which something should no longer be available is known and static, the code which performs that operation can just check if that time has already passed, no?  What does disableTickets(ticketsToDisable) actually do?

Does this answer your question? How to run a function at specific time & date?

@David
disableTickets(ticketsToDisable) is about removing the ticket buy option from UI.
I see your point, but at that known & static time, the buy option for that specific ticket needs to be removed from the UI automatically without any user action, that I am chasing.

@Dholu: When the UI loads, that known time can be provided by the server to the UI.  In that case the linked duplicate is probably a good approach for "scheduling" that change to occur client-side.  As a separate step you can add functionality in the server-side operation which would be invoked by that UI element such that it just checks if the time has passed and returns an error.  (In case the user is clever and circumvents the client-side restriction.)

I'd say you should still have a "protection" on a backend to prevent processing you request if the users would "undisable" the input directly from DOM. You could implement some '/getTicketState endpoint, which will return some metadata and also if it should be enabled in the UI. Then in React you could poll this endpoint with setInterval

@Heretic Monkey different time zones would create issues with new Date() right ? or am I missing something ?

You're missing something. Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds that have passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z. As long as you take the Date's valueOf() and subtract Date.now() from it to get timeToDisable, time zones don't enter into it.

There should only be one specific Timezone set for the raffle draws to be drawn, it provides fairness. (If this draws are global)
